# Getting NaN when using index + 1

Tags: angular, mat-table

this following statement is giving me `NaN` for `{{ i + 1}}`:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;" style="text-align: center; padding-right: 3px;">{{i + 1}}</td>
```

tried so many things not getting it right.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="sl">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="text-align: center;"> SL No.</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;" style="text-align: center; padding-right: 3px;">{{i + 1}}</td>
  <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="color: white; border: none;"></td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="sl">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="text-align: center;"> SL No.</th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;" style="text-align: center; padding-right: 3px;">{{Number(i) + 1}}</td>
   <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="color: white; border: none;"></td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Try `{{ +i + 1 }}`.

Comment: That is odd, tried to reproduce but I couldnt, please if you can, provide a Stackblitz.